# ExtJS textfield with LabelAlign Top (CENTER)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, textfield, extjs4.1

Is there any config option to put the lavel on top with center align for a textfield.

```
  {
    xtype:'numberfield',
    labelAlign:'top',
    labelSeparator:'',
    fieldLabel: 'Title',
    flex:1 
  }
```

Its working fine with label on top but aligned  to left. I want to be centeraligned with top.

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a class to the label using `labelClsExtra`:

> An optional string of one or more additional CSS classes to add to the
>   label element. Defaults to empty.

For example:

```
labelClsExtra: 'your-class'
```

And in your style sheet:

```
.your-class {
    text-align: center
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/qazN3/